# Calling script-level Python functions from the Linux command line

Tags: python, linux, shell

How can I create functions and software for my Linux server? Let me explain this in a bit more detail.

So for my Linux server which I access with my SSH client, I have made a few Python scripts that work fine, but what I really want to do is have these Python scripts active all the time, such that I can execute functions I've created in the script (such as "def time(): ...") just by typing "time" in to the command line rather than starting up a script with ./script-name.py and then type "time". Do I need to install my Python files in to the system in some way?

I struggled searching Google because I didn't fully understand what to search, and results that came up weren't really related to my request. I did find the cmd Python module and learned how to create cmd interpreters, however, in order for me to access the commands I defined in the cmd interpreter, I had to first start the script, which as I explained above, not what I am looking for.

How can I make script-level Python functions callable from the Linux command line?

Comment: Lookup `supervisord` also, this is very vague.

Comment: You could just add functions to your `.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` like `function time () { python /my/dir/my-script.py }`

Comment: (`time` is a very bad name because it shadows the *command* `time` and to get it back you'd have to type `\time` instead.)

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Python, you'll still need to fire up the interpreter, but you can make that happen automatically.

Start by making your script executable. Run this command in the shell:

```
chmod +x script-name.py
ls -l script-name.py
```

The output of `ls` should look something like this (note the `x`s in the left-hand column):

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 me me     4 Jan 14 11:02 script-name.py
```

Now add an [interpreter directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_directive) line at the top of your script file - this tells the shell to run Python to interpret your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Then add code at the end of the file that calls your function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    time()
```

The `if` statement checks to see if this is the file that is being executed. It means you can still import your module from another Python file without the `time()` function being automatically called, if you want.

Finally, you need to put your script in the executable path.

```
mkdir -p $HOME/bin
mv script-name.py $HOME/bin/
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Now you should be able to run `script-name.py`, and you'll see the output of the `time()` function. You can rename your file to whatever you like; you can even remove the `.py` extension.

Additional things you can do:

- Use the [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) to add command line arguments, e.g. so you can run `script-name.py time` to execute the `time()` function
- Put the script in a system-wide path, like `/usr/local/bin`, or
- Add the `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` line to your [`.bashrc`](https://superuser.com/questions/49289/what-is-the-bashrc-file) so that it happens by default when you log in

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is by far more complete and more informative than mine. I just wanted to offer a quick and dirty alternative.

```
echo "alias time='<your script> time'" > ~/.bashrc
bash
```

Like I said, quick and dirty.